# JScrollpane does not notice another JScrollpane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I have a JFrame which contains a JSplitPane in a JScrollPane (so the user can scroll if the window is to big). The JSplitPane contains a JTabbedPane as the top component and graphics as the bottom component.
Now i want to read a .csv und display it in my JTabbedPane. I can scroll through the list with a second JScrollPane. Here comes the problem, when i import the .csv in my programm, the first JScrollPane seems not to notice that there is a second JScrollPane for scrolling the list and then my window gets a lot of free space to scroll.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP, JTabbedPane.WRAP_TAB_LAYOUT);
JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT);
splitPane.setTopComponent(tabbedPane);
splitPane.setBottomComponent(graphics());
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(splitPane);
frame.add(scrollPane);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

When i import the .csv I add a new JPanel to the tabbedPane. The JPanel contains a list from the data from the .csv

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);
// here comes the code for the list
tabbedPane.add(scrollPane);
```

I hope you understand my problem, it is hard to explain.

Edit: Pictures from before and after importing the .csv may help you to understand.

[image: before]

[image: after]

Comment: It doesn’t make much sense to put a split pane into a scroll pane. Maybe you want to put two scroll panes into a split pane…

Comment: The top component should not have a scrollbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the first scroll pane. Add the split pane directly to the CENTER of the BorderLayout used by the frame. As the frame resizes all the space will be allocated to the split pane.

You can then use:

```
splitPane.setResizeWeight(1.0);
```

Now all the extra space will go to the second component as the frame is resized. Therefore the scrollbar for that component will appear/disappear as required.